# SSH to Wireguard server while router running Wireguard client VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have a (GL.Inet Beryl) router connecting to a Wireguard server on my AWS instance, and my (MacOS) laptop connects to the router and is thus protected.

When I was running the Wireguard client on my laptop, I could also SSH into the server. However since running a (identically configured) Wireguard client on the router, my laptop cannot SSH to the server:

```
ssh: connect to host [my public IP] port 22: Connection refused
```

The port is open for all IPs. What have I missed?

When Googling, I often end up at someone recommending:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However I don't understand what this is doing so am reluctant to give it a go. I did try excluding my server's IP in AllowedIPs, but this crashed my router.

Thanks for any tips.